# .htaccess redirect htttp to https effecting secondary domains

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am using the following .htaccess file to direct all my users from HTTP to `https://www.mysite.com` which works fine  (`https://www.` are prefixed all the time).

```
rewriteengine on

rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
rewritecond %{HTTPS} !=on
rewriterule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

My Problem is that other secondary domains (which don't have SSL) which are hosted on the same hosting are trying to go to `https://www.myanothersite.com` to which the browser shows the security error.  Disabling the `.htaccess` files removes the security error from my secondary domains but then my primary domain is not redirected to `https://`.

How should I rewrite the `.htaccess` file so that my primary domain (which has SSL) resolves to `https://www.mysite.com` and my secondary domains on the same hosting resolve to `www.myanothersite.com`? (`www.` should always be prefixed on my secondary domains).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

# add www.    
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|[0-9]+)\. [NC]
rewriterule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# rdirect to https only for primary.com
rewritecond %{HTTPS} !=on
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?promary\.com$ [NC]
rewriterule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That comment will not help anybody :) Explain what doesn't work.

Comment: Problem solved Partially when I type shadikarishta.com then i am redirected to 404 page with URL https://www.shadikarishta.com/%5bR=301,L%5d  Removing [R=301,L] from the code solved my problem  but now the site becomes slow to resolve than earlier and on chrome the padlock icon becomes grey.  The code which I was previously using showed the padlock icon green all the time.  At this stage also i checked on whynopadlock.com and it says that all items on my page are secure.  I think that due to current redirection the padlock has become grey.  When I refresh the grey padlock page it becomes green

Comment: Ah sorry there a space missing in my first rule. Check edited code now.

Comment: Problem solved.  Thanks a lot.  Just a small query,  is htaccess the technically correct option for sending my visitors always to a https://www  prefixed secured URL or there is some other best option available ??  If there is..then what is that option..  because I think that this makes the site homepage a bit slow to resolve.  My site is developed in php mysql

Comment: mod_rewrite rules as you now have are the best tools for this redirection. For improving speed you can move above code to your Apache config and then disable .htaccess via Apache config. However you will gain very little in doing so.

Comment: please tell me how to apply mod_rewrite rules for the same process

Comment: You are getting confused, my answer is based on mod_rewrite rules itself.

Comment: thanks..  when .htaccess was disabled  the dedicated/static IP allotted to me 182.50.151.211  when typed in the URL bar resolved to my primary domain shadikarishta.com.  But after applying the htacess file when I type the dedicated ip the browser automaticall prefixes www in front of that ip and the site is not resolved.  Please tell me how to fix it.  Many thanks in advance

Comment: ok now the site is resoving by typing the dedicated ip but it continues to show the ip address in the URL bar after loading. i want that after resolving it should show my site name with https and www prefixed.  I tried the ip of other site and they resolve to their site with their name on the url. Thanks again